# PayPal Checkout not showing correct total amount in react app

Tags: reactjs, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, mern

Good morning. I am trying to integrate PayPal check out in my React app. Everything works fine except that the Paypal Checkout amount is not showing the same as the total cart amount. Checkout amount is fixed at $0.01 and not changing as cart amount changes. Please what could i be doing wrong ??? This is the code

#cart.js code

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { GlobalState } from "../../../GlobalState";
import axios from "axios";
import PayPalButton from "./PaypalButton";

function Cart() {
  const state = useContext(GlobalState);
  const [cart, setCart] = state.userAPI.cart;
  const [token] = state.token;
  const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getTotal = () => {
      const total = cart.reduce((prev, item) => {
        return prev + item.price * item.quantity;
      }, 0);

      setTotal(total);
    };

    getTotal();
  }, [cart]);

  const addToCart = async () => {
    await axios.patch(
      "/user/addcart",
      { cart },
      {
        headers: { Authorization: token },
      }
    );
  };

  const increment = (id) => {
    cart.forEach((item) => {
      if (item._id === id) {
        item.quantity += 1;
      }
    });

    setCart([...cart]);
    addToCart();
  };

  const decrement = (id) => {
    cart.forEach((item) => {
      if (item._id === id) {
        item.quantity === 1 ? (item.quantity = 1) : (item.quantity -= 1);
      }
    });

    setCart([...cart]);
    addToCart();
  };

  const removeProduct = (id) => {
    if (window.confirm("Do you want to delete this product?")) {
      cart.forEach((item, index) => {
        if (item._id === id) {
          cart.splice(index, 1);
        }
      });

      setCart([...cart]);
      addToCart();
    }
  };

  const tranSuccess = async (payment) => {
    console.log(payment);
  };

  if (cart.length === 0)
    return (
      <h2 style={{ textAlign: "center", fontSize: "5rem" }}>Cart Empty</h2>
    );

  return (
    <div>
      {cart.map((product) => (
        <div className="detail cart" key={product._id}>
          <img src={product.images.url} alt="" />
          <div className="box-detail">
            <h2>{product.title}</h2>

            <h3>${product.price * product.quantity}</h3>
            <p>{product.description}</p>
            <p>{product.content}</p>

            <div className="amount">
              <button onClick={() => decrement(product._id)}> - </button>
              <span>{product.quantity}</span>
              <button onClick={() => increment(product._id)}> + </button>
            </div>

            <div className="delete" onClick={() => removeProduct(product._id)}>
              X
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}

      <div className="total">
        <h3>Total: $ {total}</h3>
        <PayPalButton total={total} tranSuccess={tranSuccess} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Cart;
```

### PayPal button code

```
import React from "react";
import { PayPalScriptProvider, PayPalButtons } from "@paypal/react-paypal-js";

export default class PayPalButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const onSuccess = (payment) => {
      console.log("The payment was succeeded!", payment);
      this.props.tranSuccess(payment);
    };

    const onCancel = (data) => {
      console.log("The payment was cancelled!", data);
    };

    const onError = (err) => {
      console.log("Error!", err);
    };

    let env = "sandbox"; // you can set here to 'production' for production
  
    let total = this.props.total;

    let currency = "USD";

    const client = {
      sandbox:
        "ARhnfWu_QrcGQa-PdvaY1RVriEmqGiSkfEWf-plauZQpQN_gyxaLjH9RXOhdQw7fxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      production: "YOUR-PRODUCTION-APP-ID",
    };

    let style = {
      size: "small",
      color: "blue",
      shape: "rect",
      label: "checkout",
      tagline: false,
    };

    return (
      <PayPalScriptProvider
        options={{
          "client-id": "ARhnfWu_QrcGQa-PdvaY1RVriEmqGiSkfEWf-plauZQpQN_gyxaLjH9RXOhdQw7fxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        }}
      >
        <PayPalButtons
          env={env}
          client={client}
          commit={true}
          total={total}
          currency={currency}
          onError={onError}
          onSuccess={onSuccess}
          onCancel={onCancel}
          style={style}
        />
      </PayPalScriptProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What version of paypal buttons do you use. The props you use does not match the ones they use in their examples
https://paypal.github.io/react-paypal-js/?path=/docs/example-paypalbuttons--default

Comment: An older version. I am trying to integrate this newer PayPal SDK and thats where the confusion is coming from

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a `createOrder` function anywhere. You need one, and it needs to invoke actions.order.create() with a JSON object that uses your `total` to set the amount.

See examples in [the react-paypal-js storybook](https://paypal.github.io/react-paypal-js/?path=/docs/example-paypalbuttons--default).

Comment: my challenge is coming from the createOrder and onApprove functions which i am trying to add